# Identify this Screw - Came with Google Nest Sensor

Tags: screws

[image]

Is there a name for this type of screw? It came with a Google Nest Sensor, I was hoping to mount my router and modem to the wall with similar screws. Almost a barbell-like shape that hangs the sensors very snug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that they are called `double-headed bear claw hangers`.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Double-headed+Bear+Claw+Hangers&iax=images&ia=images